# Running WCF self-hosted in multiple web application worker processes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, load-balancing

In a web application I run a simple [wcf host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/hello");

using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), baseAddress))
{
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    host.Open();
}
```

I wrote it at `Global.asax/Start` . So it opens and listens on the port `8080` at the beginning of the my web application and I can invoke any methods defined in my `HelloWorldService` through `http://localhost:8080/hello`. I have published it on `IIS` and it works too and everything is ok.

The problem arises when I increase the `Maximum Worker Processes` value to `2` or more than `1`.

The point is that every worker process is a separated process which want to obtain port 8080 but the OS does not allow to more than one process to get it.

It seems the problem will solve by handling exception, so just one of processes will get the port. but that is not true! When recycle happens for the process which have the port, there is no guarantee a new worker process be executed immediately.

Notice: Any solutions which separates host and my web application is not acceptable, because the all business inside of service will be injected and controlled by my web application.

I have an idea. I will take different ports in every process and run them. Also I have read [Application Request Routing](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) to use load balancing feature to disperse one particular port to several different ports which has obtained by a worker process.

[image]

please appreciate me or give me a solution to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use port pool. On global.asax choose one of the unused port.

Web application may not a good choice to host WCF service.

Comment: Actually, my web application is not so simple! it is a modular framework which has provided a modular web platform. so every module maybe has some service to be registered in host. I am fully aware that how handle multiple services in the same port AND IN ONE PROCESS by differentiating URL. So the modules has its own namespace which there are module's services. if a new module has been registered at run-time, its services will be registered in services set and will be accessible common port.

Comment: So I know web app is not good choice but as you can see It seems we don't have other choice, Are you have a better idea? Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: I don't know how you call WCF service. Maybe, you can open WCF service on the first request not on the global.asax. How you can call service?   Channel or proxy classes?